# Alterar background com Select

Tags: javascript, html, css

dado esse trecho de código no html:

```
<label for="teste">Selecione uma opção:</label>
        <select name="teste" id="teste">
          <option id="exp1" value="exemplo1">exemplo1</option>
          <option id="exp2" value="exemplo2">exemplo2</option>
          <option id="exp3" value="exemplo3">exemplo3</option>
          <option id="exp4" value="exemplo4">exemplo4</option>
        </select>
```

Como faço para alternar/alterar o background aplicado na tag body, dependendo da opção selecionada?

Exemplo:
Se exemplo1 for selecionado, aplica background verde,
se exemplo2 for selecionado, aplica background vermelho,
se exemplo3 for selecionado, aplica background azul,
se exemplo4 for selecionado, aplica background amarelo,

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um `eventListener()` na tag `<select>`, para sempre que ela for alterada dispare uma função, e nesta função você altera a cor do background pelo JavasScript, deste modo:

```
let select = document.querySelector('#teste'); 

// Sempre que a tag select for alterada, dispara uma arrow function
select.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  tagQueVaiAlterarBackground = document.querySelector('#tagID'); //Substituir por sua tag
  if(event.target.value == 'exemplo1') {
    tagQueVaiAlterarBackground.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; //Substituir por sua tag
  } else if(event.target.value == 'exemplo2') {
    tagQueVaiAlterarBackground.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; //Substituir por sua tag
  }
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).